# Will a UK PS4 slim 500gb work in India?

Tags: ps4

I have purchased a new PS4 slim from Amazon.co.uk almost 1 month ago, and I was wondering if it will work in India. I am taking it to India; will the warranty work there, will the power supply support?

Answer (score 1):

Accroding to this [link](http://in.ign.com/playstation-4-gaming-hardware-ps4/56043/news/sony-india-to-support-playstation-4s-imported-from-pal-regio), if you buy PS4 Sony India wont provide warranty in India, only compensate half of price if your PS4 die.

Answer (score 0):

I dont see why it shouldnt work in India. After all, it is a PAL Region, and the PS4 is region free, thus allowing the PS4 to play games from anywhere in the world. The power supply, however, maybe a bit of an issue though.